# animated gifs freeze in firefox 4.0 and above

Tags: jquery, firefox, gif, freeze, animated

I'm using jquery to preload an animated gif and later on inject a message with animated gif to the code.
it used to work fine until release 4.0 of firefox. since then only the 1st frame is 
showed and the animation is frozen. (it works fine on IE and chrome)

I use:

```
$("<img>").attr("src",image);  // preload the image
```

And later on:

```
$(message).insertAfter(obj);  // inject animated gif and some text
```

[EDIT] Added jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/na2ku/35/

Comment: Please show us your code through jfiddle. Please check this: `http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/``http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_insertafter.asp`

Comment: Firefox simply freeze animations when the document location is changed. As you inject it upon form submission, it means the document location is changed to the form action. Consider using AJAX instead.

Comment: Thanks for the technical explanation. Using AJAX is not an option in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try inserting image object into the document instead of adding simple  tag.

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "image.gif";
$(img).insertAfter(message);
```